# Can I programatically access the error level set in App config?

Tags: error-handling, trigger.io

Is there a way to access config defined error level of the application ?

Something like `forge.logging.level` should be really fine to programatically handle some situations, like debugs (ie, loading the Catalyst lib / enabling debug, etc without having to manually change files but relying on the real error level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see `forge.config.modules.logging.level`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I must confess there is some confusion around the "forge.logging" namespace as described in the doc: forge.logging.INFO/DEBUG/ERROR/... are valid keys but with 'undefined' values while inspecting them. (correct shorthands are forge.logging.LEVELS.INFO/DEBUG/ERROR... And forge.config.modules.logging.level returns a string (like "DEBUG"), when forge.logging.LEVELS.DEBUG is an integer value... Quite confusing no ?

Comment: That is confusing, it looks like the docs for the logging module have gotten out of sync with what is actually happening (and don't do a great job of explaining things anyway), sorry about that! I've opened a ticket internally to update that page to be accurate and make more sense.

Comment: Seems like config internally changed yet .. `forge.config.modules.logging.level` is no longer available (the whole 'modules' moved away). 

`forge.config.logging.level` is the new getter available ..